# Android Studio Beta in Mac doesn't have button for AVD manager

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

In my Windows 7 install of ASB, I can click on Tools > Android > SDK Manager and work with the SDKs. However, in my Mac OS X 10.9.5 install, I can't find any links to the SDK Manager.

Similarly, in Windows 7 I can work with the AVD Manager through Tools > Android > AVD Manager, but can't find any links in my Mac install.

How do I obtain these features on my Mac? There is no Tools > Android in the Mac.

Answer (score 3):

> **Update and install packages: SDK Manager**

**1. Windows:** go to `Help > Check for Update...` in the Android Studio Beta (AS) menubar above. Click on `Update and Restart.`

**Mac:** go to `Android Studio > Check for Updates...` in the menubar above. Click on `Update and Restart.`

*2. We need to download and install several packages to make the download complete.*

**Windows:** in AS, click on `Tools > Android > SDK Manager` in the menubar.

**Mac:** in AS, click on the upper left red Exit button. The Welcome screen shows. Click on `Configure > SDK Manager.`

*Rest of steps are the same in both OSs.*

> **Configure an emulator: AVD Manager**

*We'll configure a sluggish emulator called an AVD, or Android Virtual Device.*

**Windows:** Open `Tools > Android > AVD Manager`.

**Mac:** Click on the red Exit button in the upper left to return to the Welcome screen. Click on `Project Defaults > Run Configurations.` Click on `Defaults` to open the folder, then `Android Application.` Under `Target Device,` click on the ... button next to `Prefer Android Virtual Device.` That will start the AVD Manager.

*Rest of steps are the same in both OSs.*

Comment: The "..." button does nothing when I click it.

Answer (score 0):

I face same issue, because 'System Images' not yet install.

1. go back to SDK Manager, Appearance & Bahavior -> System Settings
   -> Android SDK
2. in right buttom , click 'Show Package Details'
3. you will find the related System Images. Install it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WRt0.jpg)